# KiCad export board area only

Tags: pcb, kicad

I've created a board with an outline that was created on the edge cuts layer.  I've selected 'Board area only' and I've deselected 'Print board edges'.  When I try to plot the SVG file for the F.Cu copper layer, it plots the entire drawing sheet instead of the board alone.  What am I missing?  I haven't found any similar issues documented regarding svg exporting =(

I'm curious if there is a configuration setting I need to check elsewhere? Any troubleshooting advice is appreciated.

I'm using KiCad Application: KiCad (5.0.2-5)-5, release build on OSX 10.13.

[image]

Unfortunately, the svg is not cropped to the board area only.  See below 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely that you have some design element that exists outside of your expected board area.

You can check this by running DRC and looking for unconnected items (if they are copper) or by enabling all of the other layers and visually inspecting the board area.

KiCad will choose the "Board Area Only" based on all of the elements in your design, not just the visible elements, so that will include layers that are not output in your SVG.

Comment: Amazing.  I would not have thought of this.  I look into this possibility.  Thank you!

Comment: Another possibility is that you have a not quite closed outline. (The endpoints of neighboring elements must be within a quite small tolerance. Current nightly which will become version 5.1 within the next few weeks has a check for this as part of DRC.)

Comment: my buggy mouse somehow added a zig zag line on a hidden layer.  Removing the line resolved my issue.  Thanks.

Comment: We've all been there.  Glad it's working for you.

Comment: Using the newest version ((5.1.0-0), release build) it now appears there is a bug that is causing this to happen 100% of the time, before any edits are made to a ratsnest.  I say this because I've deleted my pcb files multiple times and generated them new from scratch.  After importing the netlist ratsnest into a new pcb file (before laying tracks or moving components) I attempted to export SVG, but it exports a much larger area every time.  This happens even with svg page size board area only selected.

Comment: I can't say that I follow everything you wrote.  But, if you feel that there is a bug, I'd recommend reporting it at https://bugs.launchpad.net/kicad along with an image and (ideally) a test board that demonstrates the issue.  Regressions usually get handled very quickly.

Comment: Thank you for providing the link.  I decided it would be helpful for users to see this ongoing conversation here as well.  I have filed a bug for it. with screenshots. 
 https://bugs.launchpad.net/kicad/+bug/1822645